# Some help uncovering memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a few people using my application and it sounds like, after a few days, the phone becomes less responsive and a little strange if my app is not killed.

I'd like a little bit of assistance with memory management.  I have a few questions:

1) I make very few references to static classes or variables in my application.  I have a class (in its own file), which is essentially a Singleton.  This class just has methods in it.  No variables and such.  My application makes heavy use of web-service calls and this class is the access point for that.  Calling a method in this class will boot an IntentService which makes the actual web-service call.  Here is an example.  Please notice that the callWebService method also references MyIntentService.JOB_DELETE and MyIntentService.ITEM_ALL, which are static ints in MyIntentService:

```
public class MySingleton {

    private static MySingleton mInstance = null;
    protected MySingleton() { }
    public synchronized static MySingleton getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void callWebService(Context appContext, int intUserId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(appContext, MyIntentService.class);

        intent.putExtra("job", MyIntentService.JOB_DELETE);
        intent.putExtra("data_type", MyIntentService.ITEM_ALL);
        intent.putExtra("user_id", intUserId);

        appContext.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

In my Activity, I call:

```
MySingleton.getInstance().callWebService(getApplicationContext(), ((MyApplication)getApplicationContext()).getUserId());
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?  Since this Singleton consists only of methods, would it be better to have it not be a Singleton and have all the methods be static?

2) Cursors.

I have several Activitys which use CursorAdapters.  I will query for a Cursor using an AsyncQueryHandler.  When the AsyncQueryHandler receives the Cursor, I call changeCursor on my CursorAdapter, passing in this new Cursor.  In the changeCursor handler of my CursorAdapter, I pass the Cursor to super, then set a private Cursor member variable of my Activity to this Cursor and call startManagingCursor on it.

After this, I don't do anything in the onPause() or onStop() methods to stop managing the Cursor or null it out or anything.  Is this wrong?  I'm thinking there may be some leaking going on by running a little test.  If I scroll down the ListView and rotate the screen, the Activity is "destroyed," re-created, a new Cursor is queried for, and the ListView is automatically scrolled to the place it was before the screen was rotated.  It obviously then still has access to the previous Cursor, right?  I'm not really sure how Android is doing this.

If I call mCursor.close(); in the onStop() handler, this creates a problem.  When the screen is rotated and populates, the user loses their scrolling position.  This is obviously undesirable.  So what do I do?  Do I get the scroll position, close the Cursor, and then pass the scroll position through savedInstanceState?

3) How do I run the blasted DDMS stand-alone?  If I open it with Eclipse open, it whines about an instance of DDMS already running and closes.  If I close Eclipse, launch an emulator and then launch the stand-alone DDMS, it doesn't see anything.

4) Given what you know about my Android experience (based on this post or others), what else should I be looking out for?  I've read a few articles by Romain Guy and I've gotten rid of potential problems, but there's surely more I haven't realized yet.

Comment: not an answer, but a helpful tool for finding memory issues, especially relating to object retention: I'd recommend reviewing an HPROF dump of your app with Eclipse MAT (http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Studio-for-Android-Blog/Get-to-the-bottom-of-memory-errors-with-MOTODEV-Studio/ba-p/9591 is a good explanation using Motodev studio; you can do this without it by just taking the HPROF dump and loading it into MAT yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you starting a service from your callWebService method? Just do the work in that method. If you really think it should be a service, just ditch the singleton and have you activity bind to the service and call it's method there.

And yes it's wrong, you have to close the cursor. You should close it in onStop and open it in onStart or onResume if you must. You really should close it as soon as possible.

Comment: From a Google I/O 2010 presentation, we're told to run web-service calls in Services (Threads in Services, to be specific, but IntentService handles that).  That callWebService method may be called from 10 different spots in the app; so it has been modularized to once place instead of having those same 6 lines of code in 10 different places.

Comment: There's no inherent reason to use a service for web calls, as long as they're in a different thread. Show us some code from your service. But my bet is that you're leaking cursors. What does your app do? Why does it stay in memory so long? Are you leaving a service running 24/7? You shouldn't do that.

Comment: IntentServices automatically close down when your code finishes executing.  When my IntentService processes an Intent, it takes the data passed with the Intent (ex: user id), calls a web-service, parses the JSON that was returned and writes the data to the application's database.  In some cases I query a Cursor, but, in the IntentService, I always close() and null the Cursor when I'm done using it.  The IntentService then notifies any Activitys who's list may need re-queried that new data is available via a broadcast.  The Activity hears the broadcast and queries for a new Cursor.

Comment: If you are closing a Cursor in your Activity's onStop(), how are you handling the scroll position problem?  If I'm your user, I scroll half way down a list, click some button to launch another Activity, click the back button, and I am now scrolled to the top of the list again, I am going to be very annoyed.

Comment: I've never used a CursorAdapter, but can't you retain the scroll position in a class member and then scroll to it when you reopen the cursor?

Comment: It would also appear, by documentation, that if you use startManagingCursor to manage a Cursor, you don't need to worry about cleanup. The Activity will handle it for you.